# I have a csv with inputs, I want output csv. inputs generates some urls and I want to append them to existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file with some keywords. With the keywords, I generate 10 - 15 URLs using the SERP API. I want to append the URLs to column URL with respect to that keyword. For one keyword there are multiple URLs. If I am not able to add URLs to respective keywords the keywords will be replicated with different URLs.

test.csv file

```
keyword            value         cost
electrician         15            3.6
plumber             12            5.9
```

I want result like this to output.csv file

```
keyword        value     cost         url
electrician     15       3.6        www.ex1.com
electrician     15       3.6        www.ex2.com
electrician     15       3.6        www.ex3.com
.
.
.
.
plumber         12       5.9         www.ee.com
plumber         12       5.9         www.ee2.com
.
.
```

.

This is the code I am using; I have tried it with pandas but it appends only the last URL.

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")                                                                                  
col = df['keywords']                                                                                          
for k in col:                                                                                                 
    print(k)                                                                                                  
    client_params = {                                                                                         
      "q": k,                                                                                                 
      "google_domain": "google.co.uk",                                                                        
      "location": "United+Kingdom",                                                                           
      "hl": "en",                                                                                             
      "gl": "uk",                                                                                             
      "num": "15",                                                                                            
      "serp_api_key": "********************",                     
    }                                                                                                         
    client = GoogleSearchResults(client_params)                                                               
    json_results = client.get_json()                                                                          
    #print(json_results)                                                                                      
    #print(type(json_results))                                                                                
    results = pd.DataFrame()                                                                                  
    print(results)                                                                                            
    for title in json_results['organic_results']:                                                             
        print(title['link'])                                                                                  
        df['URL'] = title['link']                                                                             
        results = results.append(df).reset_index(drop = True)                                                 
    # df.to_csv('output.csv',index=False, header= False)                                                      
results.to_csv('output.csv',index=False)
```

But this is the result I got:

```
keyword       value    cost       urls
electrician    15      3.6      www.ex.xom
plumber        12      5.9      www.ex.xom
```

Comment: What is `k`? do you mind to produce a [mcve](/lep/mcve)?

Comment: entire structure is in a loop

Comment: In your code `k` is not defined before so your code is not reproducible.

Comment: i have added entire code.

Comment: First of all welcome to SO. Here people is happy to help each other but it will be great if you have a read at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](/help/mcve). I your question you use `df.loc[df['Related Terms'] == k]` but `k` is not defined before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have `results` within your loop. After each iteration, it's overwriting the previous, thus leaving the last write as the last iteration. You need to initialise that before entering the loop, then you can continue to append to it. So something like:

**NOTE: You probably don;t want to include an api key so I took it out of your answer. You'll need to put in your api_key**

```
import pandas as pd
from lib.google_search_results import GoogleSearchResults

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")                                                                  

results = pd.DataFrame()   
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    k = row['keyword']  
    value = row['value']
    cost = row['cost']                                                                            
    client_params = {                                                                         
      "q": k,                                                                                 
      "google_domain": "google.co.uk",                                                        
      "location": "United+Kingdom",                                                           
      "hl": "en",                                                                             
      "gl": "uk",                                                                             
      "num": "15",                                                                            
      "serp_api_key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",     
    }                                                                                         
    client = GoogleSearchResults(client_params)                                               
    json_results = client.get_json()                                                          

    for title in json_results['organic_results']:                                             
        print(title['link'])                                                                  
        title =  title['link']

        temp_df = pd.DataFrame([[k, value, cost,  title]], columns=['keyword', 'value','cost','URL'])
        results = results.append(temp_df).reset_index(drop = True)                                 

results.to_csv('output.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: same problem it append last result to the keywords

Comment: well it's hard to debug without seeing the whole code. I don't know what `df` is, or `json_results`. all I can provide is the general idea since your code is not reproducible. And the problem is that you're not appending to a new dataframe, you are just overwriting it

Comment: i have another columns, i want to add them too but my program becomes very slow when i put another loop

Comment: what's the other column? is it in your test.csv?

Comment: and if the solution answers you original post, be sure to accept the answer

Comment: ok, well again, you ar enot really offering much in terms of what it is and what your expected outout would be. It may be beneficial to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: okay , sorry, i appreciate your effort. your code is working properly. i want to just add columns which is also in test.csv with urls

Comment: so add them into the temp_df. What does your csv file data look like? What do you want the output to look like? Adjust it in the questions above.

Comment: just give a look please , i use a loop but not beneficial.